# Why did George Lucas ban David Prowse (actor of Darth Vader) from appearing at Star Wars conventions?

Tags: star-wars, behind-the-scenes, darth-vader, george-lucas

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_Prowse), George Lucas banned David Prowse in 2010 from attending official Star Wars fan conventions. He reportedly gave no reason why other than Prowse "burnt too many bridges".

Prowse was on the outs with Lucas well before 2010. A stuntman was chosen for the scene where

> Darth Vader throws the Emperor down the elevator shaft.

David Prowse claimed that he, rather than Sebastian Shaw, was supposed to be in the scene where

> Luke Skywalker unmasks Darth Vader.

What caused the friction between George Lucas and David Prowse?

Comment: <comments deleted> The reliability or otherwise of Wikipedia as a source is pretty irrelevant since this is a *question* not an *answer*. If someone posts an answer based on Wikipedia, feel free to request more reliable sources. But here the OP found something on Wikipedia and wants to *ask* for more/better information. They never *claim* Wikipedia to be a reliable source.

Comment: @Randal'Thor More importantly, the Wikipedia article *cites its sources*. Wikipedia follows similar standards to this very site: you must cite your sources (which are vetted for notability), otherwise unjustified claims can and will get removed.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

[DAVE PROWSE GEORGE LUCAS FEUD EXPLAINED](https://www.hitc.com/en-gb/2020/11/30/dave-prowse-george-lucas/)

(See "bold" text below for the answer)

> Lucasfilm wished to keep the "I am your father" moment under wraps
> ahead of and upon the sequel’s initial release for obvious reasons.
>
> However, Den of Geek notes that Dave teased the reveal to the press
> beforehand, saying: "Father can't kill son, son can't kill father, so
> they live again to star in Star Wars IV."
>
> The information appeared in at least one newspaper and encouraged
> Lucasfilm to try harder to keep plot details hidden from the press.
> Although, Dave later claimed that he didn't know about the reveal and
> that it was simply a lucky guess.
>
> Later, in 1982 and a year prior to the release of Return of the Jedi,
> a UK newspaper leaked that Darth Vader would die and the book How Star
> Wars Conquered the Universe highlights that Dave was blamed for the
> leak.
>
> The previous source adds that this led to Dave being left out of many
> of the third film's scenes and when the helmet did come off to reveal
> Vader's true face, it was Sebastian Shaw's face underneath.
>
> Diving deeper into the issue of the leak, Dave recalled that a
> journalist called him one day to discuss his career as a weightlifter.
> However, the journalist began to talk about Star Wars at some point.
> Dave has since spoken about the moment:
>
> "He turned up at my gymnasium that evening and halfway through he
> says, 'You know you're being killed off in this movie, don't you? And
> another guy's playing the dying Darth Vader?' I said, "They wouldn't
> do that – they wouldn't go and unmask somebody else after I've played
> the part for six years.' He asked if I had a call sheet, and he looked
> at it and it said: 'Dave Prowse, Darth Vader, Studio 1,' and
> underneath it 'Sebastian Shaw, Anakin Skywalker, Studio 10'."
>
> **Dave remembers that the Daily Mail published a piece headlined "Darth
> Vader to be killed off in the next movie, in an interview with David
> Prowse" the next day, saying "and that ruined my association with Star
> Wars."**
>
> He added: "I was ostracized while on the movie, the producer and
> director wouldn't work with me, and Lucas wouldn't speak to me. I had
> six weeks of purgatory."
>
> Den of Geek addresses that Dave and George lost touch after the
> trilogy's production but notes that Dave was blocked from appearing at
> official Star Wars conventions in 2010 due to his participation in a
> documentary which took aim at George called The People Versus George
> Lucas.

Comment: interesting info - I'd edit the response to be just that last paragraph since that truly seems to answer the question succinctly, then include the link to the rest of the article which gives more details

Comment: @NKCampbell: Thought that too, but decided to post the whole part, but again not the whole article.

Comment: @YaroslavKornachevskyi: Honestly, the excerpt of the article's just unnecessarily wordy in terms of how much of the quote actually addresses this question. I'd suggest that you edit the answer to first summarize just the relevant information that answers the question, and *then* include the quote (however much of it you feel is relevant; I think the first several paragraphs in the quote are themselves just sort of introductory background info, and can be removed without really affecting the answer).

Comment: Prowse's supposed "leak" also incorrectly predicted there was a 4th Star Wars movie coming out.  (Well, incorrectly for several decades at least.)  And that his character would be in it.  (Again, sort of, yeah, but as a 9-year old, so he wouldn't have been playing the role anyhow.)  And Vader obviously didn't live to be in the sequels decades after *that*.  So his "leak" was only sort of accurate on 1 count.  Definitely more of a guess than a leak.

Comment: At last put the last paragraph at the beginning of the answer, then include the rest for more background.  The appearance in People v. Lucas may only be the last straw, but it also seems to be the most direct reason, rather than the paragraph in bold.

Comment: So... clever reporter tricks naive actor into revealing too much.  Prowse should have known better.

Comment: I see some of us think only the end of the quoted parts of the article matter, but IMO the whole ordeal with leaks is important because it shows that Prowse's relationship with Lucas was deteriorating while episode IV was still in production.

Comment: My understanding is that Prowse had no idea that Darth Vader was Luke's father until he saw the finished film. The line he was given to speak (which, like all his other lines, was later dubbed by James Earl Jones) was "No. Obi-Wan killed your father." So he couldn't have leaked it to the reporter.